# Examine Object at Given Memory Address

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Given a typical error message thrown by the python interpreter:

```
TypeError: <sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery object at 0x3506490> is not JSON serializable
```

Can I use that memory address to find the offending object using the python shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The only purpose of that address is to identify the object for debugging purposes.

Comment: Well crap.  If I can't grab the object's reference in the shell using that address (for the very purpose of debugging), what good does it do?

Comment: @nothankyou It's the default where no meaningful repr/str has been defined for it... You should have more traceback than that which will give you more of a hint of where it's occurred... put a `try/except` around your code and analyse it that way

Comment: @nothankyou Many error messages (like the one you give) will be applicable to all instances of a class. Otherwise use `import pdb; pdb.pm()` to drop into the debugger and examine the state of your programme.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to, it's not impossible. Just hard, and a very bad idea.

In CPython, you can use `ctypes` to convert a number into a pointer to any type you want. And to load and call functions out of `sys.executable` (and/or the so/dll/framework where the actual code is) just like any other library. And to define structures that match the C API structures.

If you're really careful, you'll get a quick segfault instead of corrupting everything all to hell. If you're really, really careful, you can occasionally pull off some unsavory hacks without even segfaulting.

However, in this case, it's unlikely to do you any good. Sure, at some point there was a `sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery` object at 0x3506490… but as soon as that object went out of scope, it probably got released, so there may be anything at that location…